# Correct way to add a block element to sidebar layout

Tags: widgets, sidebar, templates

First time experimenting with wordpress and looking for advice on the correct way to add a block of html to a sidebar. This doesn't seem like a custom widget to me as there is no functionality involved, other than displaying an image. I want to position it above a sidebar menu which exists there already - instead of just lobbing the html directly into the template file, should i be doing something else with it?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply add the html block to the built in text widget.
And as for positioning it above the menu just use the drag n' drop functionality of the sidebar widgets.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks @Bainternet! Now to figure out how to change the class of the page heading from h1 class = "entry-title" to the page name, prob worth a new topic